# Из текста вычленить последнее значение в скобках с учетом условия

Tags: excel, vba

Необходимо сформировать столбец значений для таблицы по исходным значениям другого столбца той же таблицы, содержащего в каждой ячейке значение вида:

> **1(ADCD);2(EFG);3(HJKLN)**

Как мы видим, элементы разделены точкой с запятой "**;**". Требуется вычленить последний элемент `3(HJKLN)` и его значение в скобках `HJKLN` использовать в ячейке нового столбца. При этом, если последний элемент имеет вид `5(CGHL)`, то есть за скобками стоит **`5`**, то этот элемент пропускается и берётся предпоследний. Все элементы с пятёрками пропускаются:

[image: Пример]

**Как это сделать в средствами Excel?**

Comment: По-моему, проще всего нарисовать пользовательскую функцию и использовать её в формуле.

Comment: Можно примерчик показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Нужное значение можно извлечь формулой листа:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ЛЕВБ("kk"&A2;ПОИСК(5;A2&"kk5")-1);"(";ПОВТОР(" ";9));9))
```

---

2-  Вариант *UDF*:

```
Function fExtractVal(sStr As String) As String
    Dim j As Long, sTemp As String
    
    sTemp = Split(";" & sStr, ";5")(0)
    j = InStrRev(sTemp, "(") + 1
    
    fExtractVal = Replace(Mid$(sTemp, j), ")", "")
End Function
```

В ячейку:

```
=fExtractVal(A2)
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что означают символы "kk", "kk5", пробел " " и 9 в  ПОВТОР(" ";9));9)?

Comment: "kk" - любые два символа. Добавлены для случая, когда в тексте только один элемент, и он с пятеркой. В таком случае без этих доп. символов  формула выдаст ошибку.

Comment: Первое, что делаем - отсекаем правую часть с символом 5: `ЛЕВБ("kk"&A2;ПОИСК(5;A2&"kk5")-1)` (для обхода ошибки при отсутствии символа 5 к тексту добавляем "kk5"). С правой частью будет удалена и закрывающая скобка перед ней. Теперь из оставшегося текста нужно извлечь последний фрагмент.  Заменяем открывающиеся скобки на 9 пробелов (этого достаточно - нужно не менее длины фрагмента): `ПОДСТАВИТЬ(текст;"(";ПОВТОР(" ";9))`  Получим фрагменты, разделенные пробелами. Берем правую часть: `ПРАВБ(текст_с_пробелами;9)` и очищаем от лишних пробелов с помощью `СЖПРОБЕЛЫ`. Получили чистую жемчужину )

Answer (score 1):

```
Function get_last_not_5(source As Range)
get_last_not_5 = ""
If source.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Function
End If
Dim tmp() As String
tmp = Split(source.Value, ";")
Dim i As Integer
For i = UBound(tmp) To LBound(tmp) Step -1
    If Left(tmp(i), 1) <> "5" Then
        get_last_not_5 = tmp(i)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]